# Create on click focus on CameraSource - Android QR Code detection

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, qr-code, android-vision

I'm developing an android app which allows user to check a QR Code content and execute something according read result.

In order to improve the performance i'd like to implement 2 methods:

- onClickFocus (which allows user to focus the camera when screen is clicked)
- turnOn/OFF flash (which allows user to turn on/off the flash)

I've done some digging and figured out that for manage camera and flash I need to be able to manage the `Camera` as object itself.

And here is where the nightmare begin.

I'm using the follow code to show camera result and track QR codes.

```
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;
import java.io.IOException;



public class MainReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public SurfaceView cameraView;
    private TextView barcodeInfo;
    public BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    public CameraSource cameraSource;
    public Vibrator v;
    public String textInfo;
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_read);
        v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);


        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);


        //barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_info);

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();


        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector).build();



        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", ie.getMessage());
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }

        });


        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {

            @Override
            public void release() {

            }


            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {


                    new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                        public void run() {


                            v.vibrate(500);
                          // textInfo = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;

                            MyFragmentDialog newf = new MyFragmentDialog();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newf);

                            transaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                            transaction.commit();

                        }
                    };
                }
            }

        });







    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

So, I need to get access to Camera, from CameraSource (am I right?!)
Once it is not possible, I tryed to use this [CameraSource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) class from GoogleSamples's git which allows to use setFocusMode method... But unfortunately I wasn't successful.

I also tryed to use API 21, since API 22 [no longer supports](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) Camera and CameraPreferences.

I'm pretty sure this is not only my problem, but couldn't find a way to fix it.

Anyone can help?

FIXED:

Just use this CameraSource (github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) . Yeah, I know, I've suggested it... But this time i fixed my problem! So, if you're going to use this, make sure your compile looks like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize these and define them in `OnCreate`

```
Camera.Parameters params;
Camera camera;
CameraSource cameraSource;
SurfaceView cameraView;
boolean isFlash = false;
```

Call `changeFlashStatus()` method to turn flash ON and call it again to turn flash OFF

```
public void changeFlashStatus() {
    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                    if (!isFlash) {
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        flashImage.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                        isFlash = true;
                    } else {
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        flashImage.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.greyLight));
                        isFlash = false;
                    }
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                }

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

To get the camera to focus, you need a specific area ( `Rect` ) to pass it to Camera to make focus on that area. So we have to implement `onTouchListener()` for `surfaceView` so when we touch the `surfaceView` we create `MotionEvent` which is determine where exactly you touch the `surfaceView` then we can extract `Rect` from `MotionEvent`.

Call `initCameraFocusListener()` in your OnCreate. Safely Call it after the start of the Camera

```
private void initCameraFocusListener() {
    cameraView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            cameraFocus(event, cameraSource, Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private boolean cameraFocus(MotionEvent event, @NonNull CameraSource cameraSource, @NonNull String focusMode) {
    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

    float touchMajor = event.getTouchMajor();
    float touchMinor = event.getTouchMinor();

    Rect touchRect = new Rect((int)(x - touchMajor / 2), (int)(y - touchMinor / 2), (int)(x + touchMajor / 2), (int)(y + touchMinor / 2));

    Rect focusArea = new Rect();

    focusArea.set(touchRect.left * 2000 / cameraView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.top * 2000 / cameraView.getHeight() - 1000,
            touchRect.right * 2000 / cameraView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.bottom * 2000 / cameraView.getHeight() - 1000);

    // Submit focus area to camera

    ArrayList<Camera.Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
    focusAreas.add(new Camera.Area(focusArea, 1000));

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFocusMode(focusMode);
                    params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                    // Start the autofocus operation

                    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
                            // currently set to auto-focus on single touch
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this library and it works really well, and its easy to implement

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Google Vision API Samples: Get the CameraSource to Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051973/google-vision-api-samples-get-the-camerasource-to-focus)

To autofocus use
 `.setAutoFocusEnabled(true)` on your `CameraSource.Builder()`

Comment: I tryed to. The result is 'cannot resolve method .setAutoFocusEnabled(boolean)'