# How can I Record Video Using MediaRecorder and com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource?

Tags: android, video, android-mediarecorder

I am developing a camera application with **Face Detection** using **`Camera Source`** , but I can't record video using **`CameraSource`** with **`MediaRecorder.setCamera();`** that requires hardware Camera. Any help to record using **`CameraSource`** ?

Comment: Could you post some codes that use the CameraSource and MediaRecorder? To make better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection to get the camera object.

[Modified this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051974/8614565)

```
private static Camera getCamera(@NonNull CameraSource cameraSource)  {
 Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields)
   {
       if (field.getType() == Camera.class) 
       { 
           field.setAccessible(true);
           try { 
                Camera camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) 
               { 
                    return camera;
                } 
                return null;
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
      break;
     }
   }
   return null;
 }
```

Comment: _I want to cast_  **CameraSource**  _that exists in mobile Vision to_  **Camera**  _hardware_

Comment: @SayedShalan Did it help?

Comment: unfortunately no , **MediaRecorder** opened it own camera at the time **CameraSource** is opened so conflict is occurred , i actually have the **cameraSourcePreview** and i applied some of **image processing** such **faceDetection** , i want any way to record video using this camera , or record this camera as a view!!

Comment: @SayedShalan then does the first code work? Or both codes aren't working?

Comment: first code works perfectly , but the mediaRecorder open new Camera!!, I want MediaRecorder not opens any Camera and use My actually opened CameraSource